# What does "I've flipped through the brochure" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

I've watched a Louis CK stand up comedy, and am wondering what he meant by "I've flipped through the brochure"?

> “I like life. You know how much I do? I have never killed myself,
>   that’s how much I like it. ... I like it precisely enough to not kill
>   myself. It’s an option, though, it’s totally an option. I mean, I’m
>   49, I have two kids, **I’ve flipped through the brochure a few times**.”

Comment: Not entirely sure of the context, but it seems to be a flippant remark stating that he knows something about parenting since he is middle-aged and has two children.

Comment: Need more context.

Comment: I think "nor even any useful* second language" was unhelpful and necessary. What makes a language useful, or other languages useful is opinion biased even if English is the predominant language. **"Flip through" is an idiomatic phrasal verb** and is not meant literally, so I wouldn't exactly condemn the OP, if he's not familiar with English idioms. OP-if you googled "flipped through", [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flip-through-sth) provide a clear explanation to the meaning. [Other ex.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/phrasal-verbs)

Comment: I suspect the sentence is being used as a metaphor, which is why some context is necessary.  "I don't understand women, but I've flipped through the brochure a few times."

Comment: So now the definition of "flipped through" is known, one can determine the pragmatic force beyond the utterance, one can translate that the whole utterance to mean that because he is old (49) and has 2 kids - he considers himself quite an expert. e.g. *there is no actual brochure*; in fact brochure is a metaphor for his experience and knowledge. It's like his own unique proverb. He's being quite witty and clever with his words.

Comment: So it's like having 1 idiom being sprinkled with another.

Comment: Like I said, context is needed.  Until then the question is too unclear to answer.

Comment: @HotLicks added more contextual info

Comment: He has looked through (flipped through), the **suicide prevention **brochure. Now I see. After seeing the full context.  Geesus, what a waste of time not to have the full quote at the beginning. Take your pick folks: http://suicideprevention.osu.edu/outreach/brochures/

Answer (score 15):

Given that context it means that he has considered suicide, but (obviously) has never carried through on it.

"Brochure" here is a metaphor for the thoughts and plans that would go into a suicide, and possibly the consideration of the consequences for his family.  "Flipped through" means he hasn't "studied" the option of suicide in detail, but has at least briefly considered it, as you might "flip through" (briefly review) a brochure on a car you're only mildly interested in buying.

Comment: hmm.. this does make sense now, and the delivery probably would have helped it more so

Comment: Yeah, now I have the context: Suicide Prevention brochure, now that I've seen the *full context**. The OP should have posted the entire quote.

Comment: @Lambie where did you get suicide prevention brochure? that has not be explicitly mentioned:  "Flipped through" means he hasn't "studied" **the option of** suicide in detail, but has at least briefly considered it, **as you might** "flip through" (briefly review) a brochure on a car you're only mildly interested in buying."

Comment: @aesking flipped through means read at a glance. He has flipped through the suicide prevention brochure: he is being sarcastic: http://suicideprevention.osu.edu/outreach/brochures/ There is nothing else it can mean now that I have seen the full quote.   You don't understand sarcastic American discourse.

Comment: Well, hot licks said ***as you might** ... a brochure*. Not an actual brochure. It's a simile (comparison); I hope you see that.

Comment: I would like to see where you have got this *sarcastic American discourse* from. The comedian has been controversial for his suicide jokes, among other things.

Comment: @aesking: Having looked at the **full** transcript, this quote is right at the start, where he's arguing abortion is a woman's choice. The detour to suicide is a short detour and never goes towards suicide prevention. In fact, the next part is _I’ve thought of killing myself just to win an argument._.

Comment: @MSalters. Exactly. But is he referring to an actual brochure and the suicide prevention brochure? Or has he has actual read "the" brochure? He is being witty/sarcastic; it does not mean he was referring to the "Ohio state university suicide prevention brochure." That was quite specific. Also may I see the full transcript?

Comment: @aesking: I'll write up an answer.

Comment: You forgot to retract your close vote...

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Unfortunately true.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here seems to lie in the article: *the* brochure. Which brochure?

Normally, you use *the* when there's no doubt about the identity. that might be because there's no ambiguity, or because you follow the article by something the provides the disambiguation: *the green brochure*, *the brochure Jane wrote*.

Louis CK isn't using *the brochure* in a literal sense, though. Look at the previous sentence: *I like it precisely enough to not kill myself. It’s an option, though.* Now what's a brochure? It's something that lists available options. Flipping through a brochure implies a superficial study of the options in that brochure. And this particular brochure has options to kill yourself.

It's precisely because *the brochure*  doesn't point back to an obvious brochure, that you know it's not a literal brochure but a conceptual one. This isn't unusual in comedy. Forcing the audience to think is key to making it funny.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with the most upvoted answer here. It's not a brochure of suicide; I'm fairly certain he is referring to the "brochure of life".

A brochure is a promotional leaflet filled with the most pertinent information of a given subject, usually accompanied by photos or illustrations.

Having "flipped through" it suggests Louis CK not necessarily has thoroughly taken note of everything, or is aware of all the nuances, but, having done this "a few times", is acquainted with the broad strokes.

**Louis CK here is pointing out that he has seen what life has to offer.** And he cares just enough for it to not kill himself.

The transcription and word order emphasise this interpretation: "*I’m 49, I have two kids, I’ve flipped through the brochure a few times*": he is a middle-aged man with two children, there is very little left of a typical human life that he isn't at least familiar with.

Grammatically, he uses it as [climax](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climax_(rhetoric)) or [hyperbole](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole).